# resolve object variable from foreach-object

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I'm trying to extract all files with the extention .sddb out of all archives in a folder with the extention .sdbz.

Here is how I tried it:

From the folder that contains the file test.sdbz

```
get-childitem -filter "*.sdbz" | ForEach-Object {.\7za.exe x $_.Name -o *.sddb}
```

It seems $_.Name is not resolved becaus if I use the command

```
7za.exe x test.sdbz -o *.sddb
```

from command line it works fine.

Can someone help me please?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens with that command? Do you get an error? What do you see if you echo/output `$_` and `$_.Name` in that foreach-object block?

Comment: Why do you have ``.\`` in front there? Are you running this code from the directory where it is located? Perhaps there are spaces in the names? I would also think you should be using the Fullname instead of just name

Comment: Second vote for using `$_.FullName` instead of `$_.Name`. This gives full path. Also, if you have spaces in path try `"7za.exe x $($_.FullName) -o *.sddb"`.

Comment: .\ is needed to be able to run 7za.exe. Otherwise powershell would interpret it as a cmdlet.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thanks for all the replies. I found my error and a solution.

I made the mistake of thinking that a command that works in `cmd` would also work in PowerShell.

## CMD version

```
"7za.exe x test.sdbz -o.\ *.sddb"
```

The `-o.\` is to tell 7zip to extract everything into the working directory.

It works in cmd but not in powershell.

## PowerShell version

Here is how I solved it:

```
$workingdirectory = pwd
dir -filter "*.sdbz" | ForEach-Object {
.\7za.exe x $_.Name -o"$workingdirectory" *.sddb}
```

So the `$_.Name` part worked all along. xD